# Calling stored procedure using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

i am trying to call a stored procedure from powershell by running the following. The name of the stored procedure is sp_sample (residing in ssms). But i am not able to see any output for the code in powershell and neither is the procedure getting triggered. Could someone please correct it.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=LABVM-
 40\RTC;Database=testDB;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText ="sp_sample"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.Open()
$Result = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

PS: I dont have knowledge on powershell and i picked the above code from the internet.

Comment: No output *and* no errors?

Comment: What kind of output you are expecting? You are aware that [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns only number of affected rows.

Comment: Thanks Guys for responding! The above query was indeed working, just didnt realize it. Thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -database "DatabaseName" -Query "EXEC dbo.sp_sample"
```

Comment: IIRC this depends on having SQL Management tools installed, not just the client.

Comment: Thanks Guys for responding! The above query was indeed working, just didnt realize it. Thanks once again for your inputs!!!